# PHP - Match a string pattern

Tags: php

I have multiple file names that are in the following format:

```
format 1:
Filename-11

format 2:
Filename-11-99
```

** numbers following the Filename can be any random number.

I want to create an if condition to match the second file format example:

if filename pattern has "numbers-numbers", then, else...

so if i have the following strings:

```
Orange-01
Apples-01-02
peaches-123
```

it will only match Apples-01-02.

any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Use [preg_match](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) to solve your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible solution is to use [preg_match](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php). You should check regular expressions syntax to learn what the following means:

```
if (preg_match('~\d+-\d+~', $string)) {
    // matched
} else {
    // no match
}
```

Do use http://regex101.com to work with regex. It is brilliant.